# Preparing for Magento Front End Certification

Tags: magento

I need to prepare for the [Magento Front End Developer Certification](http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/front-end-developer) and there didn't seem to be a question on this yet. How should one prepare for this certification? Are there some guides and/or test exams that I can go through?

**EDIT:**

Is there any material specifically for the Front End Certification? I am already Magento certified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a study guide available in PDF form from Magento's website. The test is multiple choice, and takes about 90 minutes to complete.

You can get the study guide here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/front-end-developer - click on 'Resources'

Most of the test revolves around XML layouts and theme fallback. Some questions focus on basic CSS principles. Here's the actual breakdown of the distribution of questions:

```
Design fallback - 7%
XML Layout - 19%
Customization of template files - 16%
Block template system - 11%
Locate files / directory structure - 7%
Javascript creation & Customization - 8%
CSS principles - 9%
Customizing look and feel - 12%
Admin Configuration scope - 6%
Internationalization - 4%
```

The test as described by Magento:

> A Magento frontend engineer:
>
> Creates and customizes Magento themes including: templates, layouts,
>   CSS, Javascript, and other components of the front end of a Magento
>   site images translations
>
> Uses the Admin Panel to: implement design-related system configuration
>   modify the appearance of specific pages (for instance, CMS,
>   categories, and products)
>
> About the Exam
>
> 65 multiple-choice questions
>
> 90 minutes to complete the exam
>
> Each question on the exam tests a skill that applies to both Community
>   Edition v.1.7 and Enterprise Edition v.1.12.
>
> No hard-copy or online materials may be referenced during the exam
>
> No prerequisites; we recommend taking [Core Principles of Theming in
>   Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/descriptions#core-principles-for-theming-in-magento) course as a first step
>
> Study Guide Available

Sources:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/front-end-developer
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/magento-front-end-developer-certification