# How to prepare for magento certification?

Tags: magento, certificate, magento-1.7

Currently i am working as Jr.Magneto developer since past 10 month and now i want decide to take exam of Magneto certified developer is it good idea to take exam ?Is there make difference during my next job interview? If yes then please provide some guidance about tutorial to learn and how much time require to preparation?please provide some guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to go through `Magento Video tutorials` at least twice and then checkout below links

http://blog.belvg.com/tag/certification

http://blog.magestore.com/category/magento-certification

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-mysql-database-structure/

<strike>http://www.ecomdev.org/blog</strike>

http://blog.magestore.com

http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/12/27/magento-certified-developer-exam/

http://quizlet.com/20443995/magento-certification-preparation-study-guide-answers-flash-cards/

http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/01/04/magento-certification-preparation-interview-questions-answers/

Comment: I would add the following web that can be very useful and is written by great people magento community. http://magecert.com/

Comment: most of the urls not working!!

Answer (score 2):

Even if this is really off topic,

- here, have my sword:
  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/magento-front-end-developer-certification
- and my bow: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8268/are-there-any-document-or-ebook-for-magento-certification-exam
- and my axe [Preparing for Magento Front End Certification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289832/preparing-for-magento-front-end-certification)

Comment: Bestowing of Knight-Hunter-Dwarf badge coming soon^^

Answer (score 0):

From the below image you can see all the certifications related to Magento or adobe commerce

[image]